# Get keyboard input in my own widget plugin

Tags: plugins, widget, ckeditor

I am making a plugin to CkEditor. It's a widget 
which is mostly just a h1 with a css class.

That is working fine, but now I need to listen to all keyboard presses when the cursor is in my plugin, because my widget need special actions on some keyboard input.

But how do I listen to keyboard events, when the cursor is in my widget? 
I can use

```
editor.on('key', function(event) {
     console.log("Got key up");
})
```

But then I get all keyboard events in the entire editor. My widget only need/want input if the cursor is within the widget